# pgfplots: Two Y-axes in different unit systems

Tags: pgfplots

I am attempting to create a graph showing some results, and to plot SI units on the left Y-axis and Imperial units on the right y-axis.  My MWE so far is getting close, but as you can see from the screenshot the right Y-axis is not scaled properly nor is it in the correct location.  What am I missing for the right Y-axis to get this displayed properly?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[%
                width=\linewidth,
                xmin=0, xmax=200,
                ymin=0, ymax=500,
                domain=2:200,
                range=0:700,
                samples=101,
                axis y line*=left,
                restrict y to domain =0:700,
                yticklabel style={
                    /pgf/number format/fixed,
                    /pgf/number format/precision=0
                },
                scaled y ticks=false,
                xlabel={Dimension Ratio $DR$},
                ylabel={Allowable Pressure (kPa)},
                every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
                legend pos=south west
                ]
                %
                \addplot[
                    smooth,
                    color=black,
                    ]
                    plot {0.05/0.1*(2*205000/(3*(x-1)^3)+0.061*0.40)*1000};
                    \addlegendentry{$E' = 0.40$ MPa}
                    %
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis y line*=right,
                axis x line=none,
                xmin=0, xmax=1,
                ymin=0, ymax=10442.72,
                ylabel={Allowable Pressure (psf)},
                yticklabel style={
                    /pgf/number format/fixed,
                    /pgf/number format/precision=0
                },
                scaled y ticks=false,
            ]
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Allowable Pressure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Comment: You need to set the same size (`width`) for both axes.

Comment: Unrelated: `\addplot [..] plot {...};` -> `\addplot [..] {...};`, you don't need the `plot` keyword there.

Comment: @Torbjørn T., thanks, that definitely fixed the size and position, but now the right Y-axis is jammed into the right margin.  Any ideas on how to fix that besides setting the width as something less than `\linewidth`?

Comment: Not really, no. You can of course put the whole `tikzpicture` in a `resizebox`, but that will of course resize the text as well.

Comment: @Torbjørn T., ok, if you want to write this up an an answer, I'll accept it so you get the credit :)

Comment: See "4.9.11 Two Ordinates (y-axis) or Multiple Axes" in the pgfplots-manual too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two axes must have the same size. You've changed the size of only one of them with `width=\linewidth`, so add the same for the other `axis`.

Other comments:

- If there are multiple settings that are common between the two axes, you can make a style with e.g.

  ```
  \pgfplotsset{myaxis/.style={width=0.9\linewidth, <other settings>}}
  ```

  and then use

  ```
  \begin{axis}[myaxis, ..
  ```
- The `plot` keyword you used in `\addplot [...] plot {..};` is unnecessary (and makes kind of a mix between the plain TikZ `\draw plot` and the `pgfplots` `\addplot`), I'd use just `\addplot [...] {..};`.
- In general use `\centering` instead of the `center` environment inside floats, see [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables)